# Oracle External Table Columns based on header row or star(*)

Tags: oracle, external-tables

I have a text file with around 100 columns terminated by `"|"`. And i need to get few of the columns from this file into by External Table. So the solution i have is either specify all columns under `ACCESS PARAMETERS` section in the same order as the file. and define required columns in the Create table definition. Or define all columns in the same order in the create table itself.

Can i avoid defining all the columns in the query? Is it possible to get the columns based on the first row name itself - Provided i have the column names as the first row.

Or is it atleast possible to get all columns like a (`select *` ) without mentioning each column?
Below is the code i use

```
drop table lz_purchase_data;
CREATE TABLE lz_purchase_data  
(REC_ID CHAR(50))
           ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
            ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
              DEFAULT DIRECTORY "FILEZONE"
              ACCESS PARAMETERS
              ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE Skip 1
                FIELDS  TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
                        LRTRIM MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
              ) LOCATION( 'PURCHASE_DATA.txt' ))
           REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
        PARALLEL 2 ;

        select * from LZ_PURCHASE_DATA;
```

Comment: Can you place scripts on the database server? If so, have you considered using a preprocessor directive in your external table definition to call a python / ruby / perl script that picks out just the wanted columns?

Comment: @James  Not sure how to use this method. Do you have any sample?, Is there any in built script to identify the column name from header?

Comment: Take a look at : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-mar/o21nanda-312277.html . The external table engine cannot identify the column name from the header. But it can call out to another process to preprocess the file before loading it. This is commonly used for compressed files etc. Lots of scripting languages have the read a CSV based on column names, so you can write a tiny script to read the CSV, spit out the columns you want and ignore the rest. The external table loader will just see the results of your script